# Find Screen Coordinates of WebElement in WebDirver Automation

Tags: c#, webdriver

I'm trying to find the exact Screen coordintaes for a specific WebElement. The purpose it to use User32 dll (SetCursorPos(x,y)) and move the cursor to that location. And to make call mouse_event() method in User32 dll for mouse middle wheel scroll over that element.

Is there a way to find Screen coordinates?I'm able to find the element coordinates with webelement.Location but this location is not the Screen coordinates.

I'm using c# Websriver.

Answer (score 0):

Using User32 dll GetWindowRect() or using Java script element.getBoundingRecatangleClient() will work to get the coordinates relative to the screen.